# Legal issues with nba player names, profiles, logos?

Tags: legal

I am searching for this topic and I found a similar question asked 
check here: 
[Legal issues around using real players names and team emblems in an open source game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25873/legal-issues-around-using-real-players-names-and-team-emblems-in-an-open-source)

however I have specific questions where I don't know where to ask.

So I'll make an nba-quiz mini game and I need to know if there might cause some trouble using player profile images, names, team names and logos.

I found about a dozen suck mobile apps which use real names also some use photos as well.

In case I need a permission or check the customs, where to contact? where can I find such regulations?

Lets say I am allowed to use profile images, can I use the official images found on nba.com or yahoo or any sports website?

If not, where to get all player photos? sure can't capture them one by one :)

As for team logos, there are logo-quiz apps which mentions hundreds of logos of different international famous companies, I don't think the app owner contacted each company.

Any related information would help.

Thanks

Comment: In what is your question different from the one you linked to?

Comment: Is it legal to do what you'd like to do without NBA's permission? Most probably not. _Will you be sued by them_ (i.e. _"Will you get caught?"_) is a totally different question, and really, there is absolutely no answer to it.