# Can I use "Finding Dori" as my ios game title?

Tags: legal, trademark

I am creating a fishing game for which I want to give name "Finding Dori". As the film is already released with title "Finding Dory", and they have game on App store named *Finding Dory: Just Keep Swimming*.

Is it okay if I use "Finding Dori" as my game name? Or any other possibilities to use such name? I have created Dori character in my style in different manners.

Thanks all for your quick responses and from your votes only I come to know how much people is loving copies :). Thus, I decided to use something unique. The app is under review for now.

Although the game will have updates sooner than later but I hope you will appreciate my work :).

Comment: When will you people stop trying to coast off other peoples successful intellectual property. Try to come up with a creative idea for once instead of asking about how exactly to steal a idea but not get sued for stealing it. This question made me genuinely mad.

Comment: @UriPopov I have not coped the game concept, my game is totally different. This is a marketing gimmick and lots of same name games are available on App store, that's why I am asking this. Or can I use "GAMETITLE: Finding Dory version"? As I created a fish similar to Dory and I think that's just for fun, not to steal as Dory is a character from real fish, so.

Comment: It's Okay, but people would think it as a copy of Finding Dory, and will not download it. I recommend you think of another name.

Comment: @MatthewRoh Thanks for your suggestion. But I thought it would get more hit with this name and it's free after all. What's your views on this?

Comment: I think [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/124962/how-fake-do-invented-names-of-a-football-game-have-to-be-in-order-to-avoid-cop) question covers your issue.

Comment: Don't go against Disney. If they want to shut you down, they will. And you'll get hurt.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the specifics of interpreting intellectual property law.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Finding Dory" is a registered trademark by Disney Enterprises, Inc. [You can look that up on the US Patent and Trademark Office](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/gate.exe?f=tess&state=4805:7p1rom.1.1).

A trademark is also violated when you use a name which is so similar that one might confuse it with the trademark. Most people looking for a game about the movie might not remember if the name is written with `y` or `i`, so the confusion potential seems quite high.

Note that Disney is a company which takes defending their intellectual property **very** seriously. So serious that they did in fact [repeatedly lobbied politicians to change copyright laws so their most valuable IPs would not fall into the public domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_Term_Extension_Act#Support). When you feel that there is *any* possibility your project might violate their trademarks, consult a lawyer.

Comment: There are few other games with such name like, "Blue Dora - finding dory version", "quiz for finding dory", "Just Keep Swimming", etc. So I thought "Finding Dori: GOT SWIMMING" or "Finding Dori: Tap Swimming" will be okay. What you say? Or could you suggest any?

Comment: @Mobihunterz I am a game developer, not a lawyer. You should really ask one. Also keep in mind that other people doing the same is not an excuse. They either might be in for a lawsuit or anticipate it and already have a (semi-legal) exit strategy planned. Like waiting for the C&D letter, take all the money out of the company, declare bankruptcy and leave the country hoping they won't be caught for embezzlement. When you plan such a crooked endeavour, definitely consult a lawyer.

Comment: @Mobihunterz "Other people do it" is *never* a valid excuse to break the law. +1 for "consult a lawyer". Alternatively, stop piggy-backing on other people's work and come up with your own name. The benefit if this approach is that if your app becomes popular, people will be able to find it more easily without having to search through hundreds of other similarly named Finding Dory knock-offs.

Comment: Thanks all. I should keep a different name then. Also if work is not a copy then why name it copy of something else. :)

Comment: @Mobihunterz If you update your question (to state your decision) I'll gladly retract my down vote because I wholeheartedly agree and respect your openness to the community's feedback.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for your response. I have updated the question.